# How can I programmatically add a Gradient Layer over an image in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ios8

I want to place a layer with a predefined ***Transparent to Black*** gradient on top of an UIImage whose content image is loaded via web and
creating an effect of a shadow over it.

I don't want to do it via loading a png with such a gradient.

Comment: ...please explain why the downvote. Need editing? If that so..please be welcome to do it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suggest creating a custom subclass of UIView (or UIImageView, if what you want to add the gradient to is a UIImageView). In the init method of your custom view, create a CAGradientLayer and add it as a sublayer of your view's layer. Then set up the black to transparent gradient on the layer.

You will probably need to override layoutSubviews() and change the settings on your gradient layer in case the view's bounds change.

EDIT:

I created a [**playground as a gist on github**](https://gist.github.com/DuncanMC/c41babda5709b9d41ca8) that is a working example of this:

The code looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class ImageViewWithGradient: UIImageView
{
  let myGradientLayer: CAGradientLayer

  override init(frame: CGRect)
  {
    myGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.setup()
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
  {
    myGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.setup()
  }

  func setup()
  {
    myGradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    myGradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
    let colors: [CGColorRef] = [
      UIColor.clearColor().CGColor,
      UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.3).CGColor,
      UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5).CGColor,
      UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.3).CGColor,
      UIColor.clearColor().CGColor ]
    myGradientLayer.colors = colors
    myGradientLayer.opaque = false
    myGradientLayer.locations = [0.0,  0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 1.0]
    self.layer.addSublayer(myGradientLayer)
  }

  override func layoutSubviews()
  {
    myGradientLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds
  }
}


var aView = ImageViewWithGradient(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
```

Comment: Hi @Duncan C I'm reviewing your solution right now, But I'm trying to apply this effect over an existing UIImageView because it must be inside a reusable cell of a Collection ..and it's not appearing. I have already tested your playground and suited the direction of the gradient up to my needs and it seems to work nice :)

Comment: Ok, so create a custom subclass of UICollectionViewCell that uses one of these custom ImageViewWithGradient objects instead of a normal UIImageView.

Comment: Hi @Duncan C I already managed to do it, Was way more simple that I thought, just made my UIImage on storyboard to implement ImageViewWithGradient.

Comment: Changed your UIImageView into an ImageViewWithGradient you mean?